# How to use gparted to resize hdd?

Tags: 11.10, dual-boot, windows-7, gparted, 7.10

I installed Gparted as I used to in 7.10 and was going to resize my partion when I saw that I can't resize my Ubuntu OS partion. I used to do it in 7.10 to dual-boot with Windows. But I'm locked out or something. I do not have the root acces to change the HDD. What do I have to do to make it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't resize a partition when you are using it.

So you have to use an Ubuntu Live CD, boot on it, and then do your operations from the Live environment. Eventually, you have to "swap off", that is to say turn the swap partition off by using Gparted.

Comment: Thank=) It's been some changes sins I last used Ubuntu=) I'm gonna try it out now=)

Comment: If this was the correct answer, please upvote it and select it as the best answer (green check mark).

Comment: It worked like a sharme:D Thx !