# Reinstalling Windows 7 on a new HDD which has 12.04 Installed

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, gparted

My hard disk died and I had to get a new 250GB and in the process of recovering my files from old hard disk using Ubuntu, I fell in love with it. So in my new HDD, I just installed Ubuntu first since I did not have a Windows 7 CD and I liked Ubuntu and was already learning stuff on Python.

Now its summer and I want to reinstall Windows 7 so I can play some games. Don't know how to go about making space for Windows 7 as well as what other things to do, please help.

I have about 100GBto spare so that should be more than enough, I just don't know what to do. Should I use GParted to make space and then install Windows 7 and then fix Grub? Or another easier way?

Comment: As you pointed, using GParted from a live CD its a simple way. If you can, do it, there shouldn't be any problem. Then just repair the GRUB.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/97881/how-to-use-gparted-to-resize-hdd?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The another way is to make partition use windows 7 disc. Both ways are easy. In windows 7 disc , your drive will be formatted as NTFS by default. With Using Gparted , Never forget that you have to format it with NTFS. because Windows Doesn't understand ext4 file system.

Comment: After both process, you have to fix grub

Comment: do have a link to a step by step im sorta newbie at this and i just dont wana mess up the computer. thanks ahead.

Comment: Welcome to ask ubuntu. Click on following link for partitioning using windows 7 disk. http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/52291-partition-hard-drive-windows-7-install.html

Comment: after you  have to fix grub , you can do it by http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repairrestorereinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd/